# How to calc properly the size of an image to add fade effect to it

Tags: css, sass, fade

I'm trying to add a fade effect to a banner but I can't properly calc the size of image to adjust the fade properly.

For example. if I have an image 1000x400 I need to adjust the calc to be `calc(100% - 1010px);` but if the image is 1200x400 I can't change dynamically the size to `calc(100% - 1210px);`

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 25rem;
  background-color: coral;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.background-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/1000/400/any");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}

.background-image:after {
  content: "";
  width: calc(100% - 1000px);
  height: 120%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 50px 0 100px 100px coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background-image"></div>
</div>
```

You can try it on codepen: https://codepen.io/Gabrielr472/pen/jONKNdO

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you can use css variables you can try this solution:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="background-image" style="--width: 1220px"></div>
</div>
```

and in css

```
width: calc(100% - var(--width));
```

and if you need to modify it in js:

```
elem.style.setProperty('--width', '1220px');
```

https://codepen.io/Xesenix/pen/qBWKoPY